# How do you make a list double spaced?

Tags: wiki, trac

How do you make a list double spaced and continue the number? For example

1. This
2. Shouldn't
3. Be
4. Hard

If I add a line break then the numbering restarts from 1 again. Is there a way to make a whole numbered list double spaced or at least manually add some line breaks without resetting the count?

What is the point of wiki markup, why not just use HTML? It's at least as simple, if not more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me with Trac-1.0.1:

```
 1. This [[BR]][[BR]]
 1. Shouldn't [[BR]][[BR]]
 1. Be [[BR]][[BR]]
 1. Hard
```

I think it's because wiki markup is platform-, browser- and version-independent.

Comment: Could you please explain how this works? In particular, why would you need two linebreak commands instead of one (i.e. [[BR]][[BR]] vs [BR])?

Comment: Use the wiki page editor and switch to text mode. Put in the pure wiki markup as given above and save. Then the page will be rendered as you want to have it displayed. Two linebreaks are necessary to create your desired extra line.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing falkb's valuable answer on the first two of your three questions here are some words on Wiki markup:

I strongly disagree on your notion ('why not just use HTML?'), even more after being switched forcefully from Trac to a MS SharePoint business application. Me personal experience is:

Wiki markup is

- simpler (and rather figurative/intuitive)
- allows higher typing rate
- easiler reviewable
- faster to copy-n-paste and adapt

compared to equivalent HTML markup.

Most often used features like headings and list markup are a good example - very few extra characters in Wiki, just one additional char to add/remove for making a 2nd level a 3rd level heading. After I got a grip on Trac wiki markup syntax I started making plaintext notes outside of Trac's wiki editor in the same style too for clear text structur with minimal effort.